# Google Spreadsheet datetime conversion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to match two different responses of same Date field in Google Form 
For that for one cell I am accessing its value from the spreadsheet generated by filling its response and for other I am accessing its value from the last response generated by filling second form 
In first by observing log, it stored value in this format in spreadsheet
 "Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017" (without quotes) 
 and other stored value in this format "2017-01-03" 
 And I want to compare these two values, I know if I access the spreadsheet of 2nd form it will be easy to compare but can I compare it in this format for which I don't need to access other form's spreadsheet? 
Edit: I tried to compare cells of both spreadsheets but both of them also had different formats 
 In second spreadsheet format was like 
 "Thu Mar 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value "2017-01-03" is a **string**. It carries no information about a timezone with it, so it's something you need to know (from the context in which you collected the form). Perhaps it's Asia/Kolkata, the Indian time? If so, I would format the first date as the string, using the same timezone, and compare the two.

```
var str = "2017-01-03";     // date as string
var val = range.getValue(); // date as Date object, from spreadsheet
var val2str = Utilities.formatDate(val, 'Asia/Kolkata', 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // now also a string
Logger.log(str == val2str); // test equality
```

(One can also test inequalities on strings formatted in this way, `str < val2str`).

Another approach would be parse the second string into a date object, but this is somewhat more complicated as the Google Apps Script date parser is finicky.

Comment: I splitted both string by space and made 2 new strings of form "Tue Mar 16 2017" and equated but above piece of code is just beautiful!

Comment: And when my script runs the code, for which I have set trigger on form submit, I could not see the result (which is another new spreadsheet in which I am storing results of queries) instantly but I had to manually run the script again, Can you help me with that?

Comment: This means the data is not yet in the spreadsheet when the function is triggered. You can try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before fetching the date from the spreadsheet; this should apply all pending changes. But it's more reliable and more convenient to get the submitted values directly from the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit).